# neo4j on CENTOS 6.9 keeps stopping

Tags: neo4j, centos

I'm running Neo4j 3.2.6 on CENTOS 6.9. I have two problems:

First, Neo4j keeps stopping (typically about 5 times per day). There is nothing in the debug.log at the time of the failure (although there are many lines from the time I restart the service). How can I identify the problem? Which log files would give me a clue to the problem? Happy to share log files here if someone tells me which files to share.

Second, the above problem is compounded by the fact that I can't get Neo4j to restart automatically when it fails. I believe CENTOS 6.9 uses Upstart but I'm not having much luck setting this up. How do I set up Neo4j to restart on failure in CENTOS 6.9?

Comment: Just of the top of my head ... is anything else running on that same system and are you perhaps close to having memory maxed out. Does a grep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages show killed processes ?

Comment: @TomGeudens Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction... at first I didn't find what I was looking for but when I searched the /var/log/messages file for the time when it last crashed I found
'Oct  7 18:01:59 ps2 kernel: [26574.605007] Out of memory: Kill process 2936 (java) score 213 or sacrifice child' so I guess when java is killed it takes neo4j out with it. I guess I need to look at the memory config in neo4j or upgrade my server.

Comment: Indeed. You are looking at the OOM killer in action. That means your machine is stressed for memory and in other to stay sane it will select candidates to kill. Neo4j is a java process that wants lots of memory and thus is a good candidate ...